# Link Pop-up in custom plugin

Tags: plugin-development, links

I am trying to build a plugin, for one of my current task, and at a field it requires user to provide the URL their content would link to.

I have added a text-box where user could paste the link they refer to.

But I am looking towards a solution, where I could provide a button, which opens up a pop-up (*like the one available on tinyMCE editor button*) for user to select links from various pages/posts already submitted.